# Automatically call bind() on all instance methods in es6 during constructor

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

How can I (or is it possible to) make a JavaScript base class that automatically calls bind on each of its instance methods during it's constructor?

I tried, without success:

```
class BaseClass {
    constructor() {
        // for (let i in this.__proto__) { // <-- this also failed
        for (let i in this) {
            if (typeof this[i] === 'function') {
                this[i] = this[i].bind(this);
            }
        }
    }
}

class MyClass extends BaseClass {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.foo = 'bar';
    }

    myMethod() {
        console.log(this.foo);
    }
}
```

When I set a break point in the constructor, `this.myMethod` exists, and it exists in `this.__proto__`, but it doesn't in `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(this)` in neither the class's constructor nor the base class's constructor.

Essentially I'm trying to do the *Bonus Step* in [this blog post](http://www.newmediacampaigns.com/blog/refactoring-react-components-to-es6-classes) (after the conclusion) without needing to define or call `_bind()` manually.

Comment: Why are you trying this? Bind your methods only when you need to pass them around, instead of doing it prematurely.

Comment: In my React components all of my components' methods are used for event handling and need `this` to reference the component, and not the object that triggered the event.  If there was a performant shortcut, it would be handy.  It turns out there isn't.

Comment: I'd rather recommend to do things like `this.myMethod = (e) => console.log(this.foo);` in the constructor then.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

ES6 class methods are non-enumerable, so you'd have to walk the prototype chain yourself.

```
for (let obj = this; obj; obj = Object.getPrototypeOf(obj)){
  for (let name of Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj)){
    if (typeof this[name] === 'function'){
      this[name] = this[name].bind(this);
    }
  }
}
```

Avoiding this complexity is why that "Bonus Step" was explicitly naming the things to bind. It's also going to be way slower to do this on every single object create.